# Updating a column in a table based on its value from another table on id match

Tags: sql, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have two tables:

```
activities (
    org_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    lang text,
    timestamp bigint,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((org_id, user_id), timestamp)
```

and

```
metadata (
    user_id text,
    org_id text,
    lang text,
    date_str text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, org_id), date_str)
```

Given:
`activities.rows >> metadata.rows`

I need to

```
update metadata and set metadata.lang = activities.lang for all rows in metadata,
```

```
where metadata.user_id = activities.user_id and metadata.org_id = activities.org_id
```

Q: What would be an elegant short cql query to achieve the same?

I tried:

```
update metadata set metadata.lang = (select activities.lang from
```

```
activities where activities.user_id = metadata.user_id and activities.org_id = metadata.org_id)
```

which obviously fails for cardinality violations.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the issue much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQL doesn't support this kind of update statements (see the [docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#update)). You need to provide actual values in the `where` condition.

So you'll need to do everything in your code (fetch data, generate update statements, etc.), or you can use something like Spark, with something like this (not tested):

```py
metadata = spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="metadata", keyspace="test")\
    .load()\
    .select("user_id", "org_id")
activities = spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="activities", keyspace="test")\
    .load()\
    .select("user_id", "org_id", "lang")
joined = activities.join(metadata, 
   (metadata["user_id"] == activitites["user_id"]) &
   (metadata["org_id"] == activities["org_id"]), "inner")\
   .select(metadata["user_id"], metadata["org_id"], "lang")
joined.write\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="metadata", keyspace="test")\
    .save()
```